# Zend Framework -> Zend_Log via application.ini => insert() on a non-object error

Tags: zend-framework, zend-log

I am trying to get logging via the application.ini file going and I am getting stuck with an error.

```
resources.log.db.writerName = "Db"
resources.log.db.writerParams.db.adapter = "PDO_SQLITE"
resources.log.db.writerParams.db.dbname = ROOT "/data/tmp.db3"
resources.log.db.writerParams.db.table = "logs"
resources.log.db.writerParams.db.columnMap.priority = "priority"
resources.log.db.writerParams.db.columnMap.message  = "message"

Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in /var/www/libs/zend/library/Zend/Log/Writer/Db.php on line 137
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot instantiate a Database Logger from an Ini configuration yet.

Either setup the Logger in your Bootstrap within an `_initLog` method or extend the regular Zend_Log class to use the default DB adapter or better, to instantiate, the DB adapter given in the application.ini.

See here:

- [Zend_Log in application.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968253/zend-log-in-application-ini)

---

**And in case you are interested why it doesn't work from application.ini:**

The Log Resource Plugin will call the `Zend_Log::factory` Method, which in turn will check the Writer you defined and then call this Writer's `factory` method to create a new Writer instance. But `Zend_Log_Writer_Db` expects the first argument to it's constructor to be a `Zend_Db_Adapter` instance, but it will not enforce it.

You cannot supply an instance from the ini file. The writer will check if the _db property is set when you try to write and throw an exception when it's null. But you supplied a string for the property, so _db is not null and it won't throw. Instead, when trying to write your writer will `$this->_db->insert()`, causing the error, because _db should be the missing `Zend_Db_Adapter`, but is a string, e.g. a non-object.

See the factory() and _write() method for details:

- http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Log/Writer/Db.php

Answer (score 6):

I submitted a fix here:
http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9497

Answer (score 0):

I used this the bootstrap:

```
protected function _initLog()
{
    $options = $this->getOption('resources');
    $db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
    $options['log']['db']['writerParams']['db'] = $db;

    $logOptions = $options['log'];
    $logger = Zend_Log::factory($logOptions);
    $logger->addPriority('DBLOG', 9);
    Zend_Registry::set('logger', $logger);
}
```

Then you can use the application.ini for the other settings:

```
resources.log.db.writerName = "Db"
;resources.log.db.writerParams.adapter = <<this must be a database connection, configured in bootstrap>>
resources.log.db.writerParams.table = "users_logs"
resources.log.db.writerParams.columnMap.id  = "id"
resources.log.db.writerParams.columnMap.created  = "created"
resources.log.db.filterName = "Priority"
resources.log.db.filterParams.priority = 9
resources.log.db.filterParams.operator = "=="
```